# How to use OAuth 2.0 correctly in SPA?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization, identityserver4

I'am working on an project where we have a Vue.js Frontend and a Microservices architecture for the backend hosted in Azure Service Fabric.

We wan't to add an IdentityService for authentication using IdentityServer4.
What we want to achieve is a login that is basically the same as stackoverflow provides: 
You can login on the website with an embedded login or use external providers like Google and Facebook.

My question only concerns the embedded login.
I have read articles that state using Authorization Code Grant with PKCE is the best way in my scenario. Moreover they say, that Ressource Owner Password Grant should not be used. 
But as far as I know, with this flow it is not possible to embed the login to our own website. It will always be a redirect to the IdentityService.

How do Stackoverflow achieve this? Do they use Resource Owner Passwort Grant?

Thank you!

Comment: When you use Google or Facebook login, the authorization servee is that of Google or Facebook. When you use your app native login, you develop your own authorization server. So, the authorization code flow is valid for all

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I welcome you to check how Stackoverflow (SO) handle their user registration process.

SO allows you three options. Login through Google, Facebook or register directly to SO. When someone use Google Or Facebook, SO uses Authorization code flow. User is redirected to respective login page. Once you login there, SO receive user profile details from those identity providers, which allows SO to complete the profile and onboard the user.

But when someone use built in register page, it is simply good old registration page. There is no OAuth involved there. SO obtain end user credentials, complete the profile and save them at their backend.

In your scenario also, you can omit OAuth and use a built in registration or login page. Only concern is the maintenance burden of end user credentials.